# mysql insert query inserts zeros with some values

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am a beginner in php and mysql and am trying to write code to insert values into a table. The problem is some variables like `$upval` and `$aday` are inserted correctly but `$course` and `$chour` are inserted as zeros, notice that I echo the (`$course` and `$chour`) before the insert query and the echo prints the correct values(not zero).

```
$res1=mysql_fetch_object($result1);
$course =$res1->cid;
$result2= mysql_query("select thoure from $tbl_name3 where cid='$course'");
$res2=mysql_fetch_object($result2);
$chour =$res2->thoure;
$sql ="insert into $tbl_name2 (SID,Cid,Tid,Adate,Ahoure) values ('$upval','$course','2','$aday','$chour')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

also I try another way to write query but the same problem

```
$sql ="insert into $tbl_name2 (SID,Cid,Tid,Adate,Ahoure) values ('$upval','".$res1->cid."','2','$aday','".$res2->thoure."')";
```

Comment: You should print out `$sql` after you have put in the variables.  The answer would then (probably) be obvious.

Comment: Are `$course` and `$chour` numbers or strings? Are the corresponding table columns equipped to handle the data you're inserting? If you try to enter a `string` into an `int` field, it will go in as 0

Comment: @Gordon Linoff printed $sql=insert into absent (SID,Cid,Tid,Adate,Ahoure) values ('65','','2','2014-05-06','')

Comment: @Mark M    cid field is int(11) and $course value returned from field cid in another table which have the same type int(11)

Answer (score 0):

This is your SQL statement:

```
$sql=insert into absent (SID, Cid, Tid, Adate, Ahoure)
     values ('65','','2','2014-05-06','')
```

If `Cid` is being inserted as `0`, that is because `Cid` is a numeric type (probably integer of some sort) and strings are converted to numbers.  So, `''` is inserted as to `0` into a number.  Why the value is set to an empty string, I do not know.

Comment: i echo $course=26 and $chour=2 just before insert query